# readyState does not get past 1

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Trying to put data into an XML through javascripts open() function.
but The website does not get past readyState 1, 
Below is the the Javascript code

```
function addItem()
{
    var name = document.getElementById('Iname').value;
    var price = document.getElementById('Iprice').value;
    var quantity = document.getElementById('Iquantity').value;
    var description = document.getElementById('Idescription').value;
    xHRObject.open("GET", "listing.php", true);
    xHRObject.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xHRObject.readyState == 4 && xHRObject.status == 200)
        {
            document.getElementById('Information').innerHTML = xHRObject.responseText;
            xHRObject.send(null);
        } 
    }
}
```

I do not know if it is an error with the PHP, but its quite large so i will only post it in if required.

Comment: Have you set up any error trapping in your php file? Or dit you look at the headers you are receiving after the ajax-call? There could be a lot of information there.

Comment: Nah i used firebug to alert the ready state and status

Comment: Most likely it is an error in your php file. Replace the content of `listing.php` with only `echo 'ok';` and see if readyState changes.

Comment: @Michel I tried it that way and still it comes up with nothing..

Comment: When are you checking it?

Comment: @Scimonster sorry i fixed my problem but thank you i dont know how to close the question..

Comment: If it was something other than a typo that was the problem, you can post an answer to the question instead of closing it. If it was a typo, it can be closed (though it may take a while).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an error with the browser functionality, worked fine in firefox.